# JQL to constrain on parent status

Tags: jira, jql

I've been trying to write a JQL query that selects all sub tasks for all stories which have a specific status.

The problem is that stories exist in one workflow where as my sub-tasks exist within another.

Ideally, I'd like to say:

```
parent IN (status = "With dev team") AND status = "To-do"
```

to yeild all sub-tasks with "To-do" status where their parent Story has the "With dev team" status.

However, after googling all day and trying many, many different things it appears as though this is impossible. We're using the cloud version of JIRA so a lot of plugins are unavailable.

I've also tried altering my workflows to set a field on sub-tasks when their parent status changes but this also seems impossible.

Is there something which links sub-tasks to stories that I can 'get at' via JQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Script Runner plugin and a query like
ex:

```
project = SWE and issueFunction in parentsOf("status =With dev team") and issueFunction in subtasksOf("status=To-do")
```

Comment: This plugin isn't available for the cloud instance of JIRA.